# How do you call a dictionary item inside a <span> java script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a feature in a website that lets you use a dictionary to store the club name, event, and time.

```
 var clubName = {};
    var event = {};
    var time = {};

    var dict = new Map();
    dict.set(clubName, "Girls who Code");
    dict.set(event, "Guest Speaker");
    dict.set(time, "2:30 Feb");
```

I've done this to create the dictionary

```
<div className="font-weight-bold">
  <small className="text-black-50 font-size-sm d-block mb-1 text-uppercase">
      Green Club
   </small>
  <span className="text-black-50 font-size-lg mt-1">Guest speaker event<br></br></span>
  <span className="text-black-50 font-size-sm mt-1"><br></br>February 31, 2021<br></br></span>
  <span className="text-black-50 font-size-sm mt-1">3:30-4:30<br></br></span>
</div>
```

That is the code that I am trying to implement the item in. How would I call the dictionary item inside of it? I'm a beginner to JS so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Side note: BR element uses a self closing tag: `<br/>` is all that is needed for a single line break. Similar to the way `<img/>` and `<input/>` do the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<div className="font-weight-bold">
  <small className="text-black-50 font-size-sm d-block mb-1 text-uppercase">
      {dict.get('key')}
   </small>
  <span className="text-black-50 font-size-lg mt-1">
      {dict.get('key')}
<br></br></span>
  <span className="text-black-50 font-size-sm mt-1"><br></br>
      {dict.get('key')}
<br></br></span>
 
</div>
```

You can use that way to show any data inner a React component UI